# legendres polynomial and recurrence formula or rodrigues method

Tags: legendre-polynomials

im not being able to do the below sum....tried with recurrence and all other methods not coming please help
The question is given below:-
P'n+1 +P'n= P0+3P1 +5P2 +.....+(2n+1)Pn 
where Pn= legendres polynomial

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Write your questions clearly. Please use MathJax . See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Legendre polynomial's property
$$P_{m+1}' - P_{m-1}' = (2m+1)P_m$$
Summing, we get
$$\sum_{m=1}^{n} (2m+1)P_m = \sum_{m=1}^{n} (P_{m+1}' - P_{m-1}') = P_{n+1}'+P_{n}'-P_{1}'-P_{0}'= P_{n+1}'+P_{n}'-1$$
As $P_0=1$, this can be rewritten as
$$P_{n+1}'+P_{n}' = \sum_{m=0}^{n} (2m+1)P_m$$